# Youtube API v3 get comments

Tags: google-api, youtube-api

I am using  [Comments: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/list) method

Request

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/comments?part=snippet&parentId=ay4MKe1u7Ec&key=`{MY_KEY}`
```

I use API get comments return this

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#commentListResponse",
 "etag": "\"xmg9xJZuZD438sF4hb-VcBBREXc/pGLBhpjR05yQoJV31WoAx2PEFVw\"",
 "items": []
}
```

Comment: Probably because there is no results for parent id ay4MKe1u7Ec

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: Check the video on YouTube to see if it has any comments? Maybe that video doesnt have comments.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The comments->list method is only used when you need to get additional info about comments where you already know the comment ID ... or in the case of your URL, if you are trying to get more details about comments that are replies to a parentID. In other words, you can't put a videoID into the comments->list method.

What you want is the commentThreads->list endpoint:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=snippet&videoId=ay4MKe1u7Ec&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

That'll give you all the comments with their IDs ... you can take those IDs, then, and run them through the comments->list endpoint to get more granular info.

Comment: commentThreads->list can return maximum of 100 comments. I could see nextPageToken in the response. How to traverse and retrieve all the comments?