# How to find the value of allThreadsRelatedToChannelId for the CommentThreads endpoint in youtube data api

Tags: web-services, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, endpoint

I am trying to get information about the comments on youtube video. I need comment id and from the following stackoverflow answer- [Youtube API v3 get comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30590003/youtube-api-v3-get-comments?answertab=active#tab-top), I tried using the CommentThreads endpoint. Just the snippet and video id throws error 400 - "Incompatible parameters specified in the request."  How to find the value of

```
allThreadsRelatedToChannelId.
```

I could not find any details of how to find its value in any documentation or search result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'allThreadsRelatedToChannelId' is the Channel Id of the Video.

For example this Rihanna video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HL1UzIK-flA&feature=player_embedded

Belongs to the channel 'RihannaVEVO' here https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC2xskkQVFEpLcGFnNSLQY0A

So 'allThreadsRelatedToChannelId' is the channel Id 'UC2xskkQVFEpLcGFnNSLQY0A'

Running the API request which just the channel Id will return all comments for the channel.

If like you say you wish to extract comments for the Video then you'll need to any include the 'VideoId' which in this case is 'HL1UzIK-flA'.

Not to confuse 'VideoId' with 'Id' which only returns comments for thread id.

API 3 params for the CommentThread.List are at developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list