# C# YouTube V3 Get comments and next pages

Tags: c#, youtube-data-api

I'm working on YouTube Api v3 at the moment and I've got some problems.
So I want to get all comments from video.

I have that link:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=snippet&videoId={VIDEO_ID}&key={MY_API_KEY}&maxResults=100
```

So I can view it through the web browser. When I use &pageToke={NEXT_PAGE_TOKEN} it brings me at the second page of comments.

But how can I copy that to a console app or listbox in winforms?

@edited:
I found how to show comments, but still have problem to jump next page.

```
    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
    {
        var json = new WebClient().DownloadString("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=snippet&videoId={VIDEO_ID}&key={API_KEY}&maxResults=100");

        JObject jparse = JObject.Parse(json);
        var data = jparse["items"];


        Console.WriteLine((string)data[1]["snippet"]["topLevelComment"]["snippet"]["textDisplay"]);
    }
```

So now I can read all comments from one page. (I will make "for" to "data[i]", now I just testing). I know how to get pageToken but how automatize that?

I will be glad for help.

Comment: pretty sure that you can remove the `&maxresults` part and it won't limit the output. see if http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30590003/youtube-api-v3-get-comments helps

Comment: It's less than 30. maxresult 100 is the max value for one page.

Comment: Right, i was looking at the wrong thing. What I would use is a while loop that checks if the next token exists for each call. Then a foreach loop (inside that while) to pull the comments out of the deserialised json file and add them to a list. From there, its a simple bind. Alternativly, deserialise each call, and add the resulting objects to a list instead, then parse later